# What is faster: '-isKindOfClass:' or '-isEqualToString:'?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm making a game in SpriteKit and want to know whether the touched node is a specific one I'm looking for. Which would be faster, giving all nodes of that custom class a NSString name and using -isEqualToString: to check it or using -isKindOfClass: to check for the specific class?

Comment: How would using isKindOfClass help you check if the name matches?

Comment: Why don't you benchmark it? Do each _many_ times and see how long each takes. Or unit test it and put it inside a `measureBlock`.

Comment: @rmaddy I just want to know if the node is a specific object for which I need to handle touches

Comment: @Rob I've never benchmarked code so I didn't really know how to do it :( but thanks for the tip

Comment: @BrunoBEly Until you've benchmarked the code and have a proven, quantifiable, performance problem, you're wasting your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Class comparisons will almost certainly be the cheaper/more efficient of these two options. String comparison is expensive because strings need flexibility in their size (also,  NSString is a cluster, the same string might be represented with an alternate data representation depending on how it was initialised) where 'class' is a known type of fixed memory footprint.

Answer (score 1):

While I have never used SpriteKit, from a game development/performance standpoint string compares are very inefficient. A faster way is to instead store a hashed string and compare against that, which is just an integer compare.

I hope this helps in deciding what is best for you.

Comment: SpriteKit has a lot of string comparison by design, nodes have a stringIdentifier and there is a childWithName:(NSString*) method for recursively searching children the way you might use viewWithTag: in cocoa or cocoaTouch.  So it appears that Apple have decided the overhead of string comparison is worth it for the readability, hence the question.

Comment: I would be shocked if `NSString`'s `isEqualToString:` method wasn't using the `hash` method comparison available to all Objective-C objects. It's hard to imagine it ever being an actual string comparison.